# How to read a hashmap in bean of class jdbcBatchItemWriter in spring batch

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch

I am trying to pass 2 sql statements to the java class which implements itemWriter to write the data to my posgres DB. I am trying to do it through a hashmap

```
       <beans:bean id="someItemWriter" scope="step"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
          <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="someSource" />
          <beans:property name="sql"  ref = "sqlStatements" > 
         </beans:property>
          <beans:property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter" ref="myPreparedStatementSetter" />
   </beans:bean>
```

ref:

```
       <util:map id = "sqlStatements" map-class= "java.util.HashMap" key-type= "java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
   <beans:entry key = "insert" value ="${fetch.some.sql}"/>
   <beans:entry key = "update" value = "${fetch.someAnother.sql}" />

   </util:map>
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type [java.util.HashMap] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'sql': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

What I am doing wrong?. How should I tackle it?

Comment: The hashmap is read, it says it cannot convert map to string, so I think that your field "sql" in the itemWriter is a String and not a map...

Comment: Do you always need both `INSERT` and `UPDATE`? Or would you sometimes need to `INSERT` but other times need to`UPDATE`?

Comment: So, it is like INSERT (IF NOT EXISTS) and UPDATE (IF EXISTS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ADDED: Sometimes Update/Sometimes Insert**

Okay, given your comment, you have a condition where sometimes you want to update, and sometimes you want to insert. There are two methods for doing this: 1) use a single `JdbcBatchItemWriter` and use a `MERGE` query. The syntax for this will vary based on your DB. 2) Use a `ClassifierItemWriter` as shown below:

```
<bean id="classifierWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
    <property name="classifier">
        <bean class="com.package.SimpleClassifier">
            <property name="insertWriter" ref="insertWriter" />
            <property name="updateWriter" ref="updateWriter" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="insertWriter" ... />

<bean id="updateWriter" ... />
```

And then a `Classifier` implementation that looks something like this:

```
public class SimpleClassifier implements Classifier<InsertUpdateObject, ItemWriter<? extends InsertUpdateObject>> {

    private ItemWriter<? extends InsertUpdateObject> insertWriter;
    private ItemWriter<? extends InsertUpdateObject> updateWriter;

    @Override
    public ItemWriter<? extends InsertUpdateObject> classify(InsertUpdateObject item) {
        if (item.getFlag() == 0) {
            return insertWriter;
        }
        return updateWriter;
    }

    // setters and getters

}
```

**Running Multiple Queries**

First, you wouldn't want to use a `HashMap` because you could not ensure the order of the SQL.

Next, what you'll want to do here is wrap multiple `JdbcBatchItemWriter`s in a single `CompositeItemWriter` like so:

```
<bean id="compositeWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter"  scope="step">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref bean="writer1" />
            <ref bean="writer2" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="writer1" scope="step"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="someSource" />
      <property name="sql" value="${fetch.some.sql}" /> 
      <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter" ref="myPreparedStatementSetter" />
</bean>

<bean id="writer2" scope="step"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="someSource" />
      <property name="sql" value="${fetch.someAnother.sql}" /> 
      <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter" ref="myPreparedStatementSetter" />
</bean>
```

This will allow you to list as many statements as you want and ensure they run in the order you specify.

Comment: I think this will allow me to execute multiple sql statements one by one. But  I have an IF condition in my class such that it runs INSERT statement if flag= 0 and runs UPDATE statement if flag = 1

Comment: edited answer above. hopefully that helps for your particular use case

Comment: You shouldn't need any reputation to "Accept" an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235